# When adding data to a table, it doesn't show up in the Foreign key of the other table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table COURSE which has two attributes COURSECODE (PK) and COURSENAME

I also have another table COURSEUNIT, which has three attributes COURSECODE (PK) (FK) UNITCODE (PK) (FK)  and CREDIT .

When I add data to the table COURSE it doesn't add the data to the COURSEUNIT table. What is the problem?

Comment: Why would it?  Can you show how you add data to the COURSE table (SQL?), and why you think this should also update the COURSECODE table?

Answer (score 4):

Foreign key does not mean that you get one row for each key in the referenced table. It only means that any row in the COURSEUNIT table must reference an existing row in COURSE.

Comment: yeah , but it isn't populating anything in the FK

Comment: @David: it's your duty to populate.

Answer (score 2):

Those are 2 different tables and you have to manage the relation, you have to insert the data first in the course table then take the id that will be generated from this insert and make another insert in the coursecode table, they will not be inserted automatically.

Comment: Oh, i thought it would populate the same ID automatically if its a FK

Comment: No, it is not done automatically..don't forget to upvote or mark as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

No problem there, that's how SQL works, you'll need a second INSERT statement to populate the COURSEUNIT table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the query to populate the second table, how else will it know what values besides the FK to put in it? Child tables do not auto populate in any database.